# sql attack secure INSERT from golang postgres when insert members and their values are few

Tags: sql, postgresql, cockroachdb

I have cockroach db table created:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wh (
   id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
   enable VARCHAR(3),
   endpoint VARCHAR,
   auth_token VARCHAR,
   client_cert VARCHAR
);
```

And golang struct:

```
type whPOSTReq struct {
    Endpoint   string `json:"endpoint"`
    Enable     string `json:"enable"`
    AuthToken  string `json:"auth_token"`
    ClientCert string `json:"client_cert"`
}
```

After unmarshaling client request populating the DB table is done by:

```
sqlCmd := "INSERT INTO mytable" +
              " (endpoint, enable, auth_token, client_cert) " +
              " VALUES " +
              " ($1, $2, $3, $4)"
 _, err = db.Exec(sqlCmd, request.Endpoint, request.Enable,
            request.AuthToken, request.ClientCert)
```

when client request has only some struct members sent (and we are not sure which) - is there a better way to build sql attack secure INSERT as above ? For example, some times only `endpoint` and `enable` are sent (remaining are not sent)?

I have tried some thing like below, but it did not work - thrown error some thing like `db exec: pq: at or near "1": syntax error`.

```
var (
    WH_ENDPOINT   = "endpoint"
    WH_ENABLE     = "enable"
    WH_AUTHTOKEN  = "auth_token"
    WH_CLIENTCERT = "client_cert"
)

    reqDecoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    request := &whPOSTReq{}
    err := reqDecoder.Decode(request)
    

    wconf := make(map[string]string)
    if request.Endpoint != "" {
        wconf[WH_ENDPOINT] = request.Endpoint
    }

    if request.Enable != "" {
        wconf[WH_ENABLE] = request.Enable
    }

    if request.AuthToken != "" {
        wconf[WH_AUTHTOKEN] = request.AuthToken
    }

    if request.ClientCert != "" {
        wconf[WH_CLIENTCERT] = request.ClientCert
    }

    keys := []string{}
    values := []string{}
    for k, v := range wconf {
        keys = append(keys, k)
        values = append(values, v)
    }

   sqlCmd := "INSERT INTO mytable ($1) VALUES ($2)"
   _, err = db.Exec(sqlCmd, pq.Array(keys), pq.Array(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a variable for each of the fields, initialized to an empty string and then depending on the request, assign a non-empty string to some (or all):

```
...
endpoint := ""
if request.Endpoint != "" {
        endpoint = request.Endpoint
    }
...
 _, err = db.Exec(sqlCmd, endpoint, ...)
...
```